# Adjusting printer vertical scaling in PPD file?

Tags: printing, cups, scaling

I've got two printers on my Linux system with CUPS 2.2.7:

- HP Office Jet 8725
- Brother HL-2350 DW

My problem is: I want to print business cards (eg. 85x54 mm), but the paper is too thick for the Officejet, so I thought I can print it on the Brother using the manual feed. Printing works, **but** the same postscript file that produces business cards with a vertical distance of 54mm each will print them on the Brother printer with a vertical distance of 52-53mm.

Is there a way to adjust the correct vertical "scaling/spacing" inside the PPD file? Brother has not provided a PPD for this printer model, so I'm using one for another model, but maybe this doesn't fit as it should.